# SQL query on product attribute table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table which include product and attribute relations as below,

```
id  proid     attributeid  attrvalid 
18  521       12           36
17  521       11           43
16  521       9            16
29  522       18           168
28  522       17           138
27  522       16           115
26  522       15           71
25  522       12           36
24  522       11           48
23  522       9            19
```

I wrote a mysql query to get product ids which matched to given attribute ids

ex- this query return product id 521 because 16 and 36 both attribute values have on 521 product(but different attibutes)

```
SELECT proid
FROM tbl_proattrconnect
GROUP BY proid
HAVING SUM(attrvalid IN (16,36)) >=2
```

but I got a problem with same attribute set values

ex- if I pass 48 and 43 (48 and 43 values are in same attribute set) I dont get any results but it should be return 521 and 522

```
SELECT proid
FROM tbl_proattrconnect
GROUP BY proid
HAVING SUM(attrvalid IN (48,43)) >=2
```

Can anyone correct this query please, I need to work both scenarios, thanks a lot

**for a real example** 
product brands like samsung and sony in same attibute if the customer select both i wanna show both, but if the customer select samsung and sony and color from another attribute i wanna show samsung and sony results which only has selected colour, i have around 10 attibutes.

Comment: What is `attrvalid`?

Comment: column arributevalueid

Comment: There is no proid here

Comment: sorry i edited table headers

Comment: Only 522 has 48 and onlt 521 has 43. So why do you expect them both ?

Comment: 48 and 43 are the values of same attribute so i wanna get both products like brand samsung and sony in same attibute if the customer select both a wanna show both, but if the customer select samsung and sony and color from another attibute i wanna show samsung and sony results which has selected color

Comment: i just saw a similer question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994218/getting-products-with-desired-attributes?rq=1 but wanna help tocreate with my table

Comment: @smithbandara it doesn't make sense. 522 also has value 16, so why isn't it included?

Comment: @smithbandara any luck on this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand this correctly (and I'm afraid I don't) if the two values are from different attribute sets, only select proids that have both? If the two values are from the same attribute set, only select proids that have at least one?

If that is the case, I walked through it like this. I need to know how many attribute groups I have, so I wrote this query to get the count of attribute groups:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS numAttributeGroups
FROM(SELECT DISTINCT attributeid
     FROM myTable
     WHERE attrvalid IN (16, 36)) t;
```

For this specific one, it will return a count of 2, because 16 is in group 9 and 36 is in group 12.

So, what you can do is put a case statement in your having clause that says if the above query returns 2, then only return proids that have 2 or more of the attrvalids. If the above query does not, you can return everything. It's a bit ugly, but looks like this:

```
SELECT proid
FROM myTable
WHERE attrvalid IN (16, 36)
GROUP BY proid
HAVING(CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS numAttributeGroups
                  FROM(SELECT DISTINCT attributeid
                       FROM myTable
                       WHERE attrvalid IN (16, 36)) t
                  ) = 2
       THEN COUNT(*)
       ELSE 2 END) >= 2;
```

And it worked on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a661cc/13).

Comment: thanks i already found answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994218/getting-products-with-desired-attributes

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(sub.proid) FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM tbl_proattrconnect
  WHERE attrvalid IN (16, 36)
  ORDER BY proid, attributeid
) sub
GROUP BY sub.attrvalid;

SELECT DISTINCT(sub.proid) FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM tbl_proattrconnect
  WHERE attrvalid IN (48, 43)
  ORDER BY proid, attributeid
) sub
GROUP BY sub.attrvalid
```

Comment: its incorrect, according to this if you try SELECT proid
FROM tbl_proattrconnect
WHERE attrvalid IN (16,36)
GROUP BY proid query it shows 2 product but it need to show one product becoz 16 and 36 are attribute values from different attibutes

Comment: @smithbandara updated, sorry I did mistake on reading your table.

Comment: soething like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994218/getting-products-with-desired-attributes?rq=1